# In Swift, how to determine the physical size of a device screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding views programatically. For example, I have a scrollView as a top-bar menu, I set its height to 60. (I am already using auto layout for placing these views)

This top-bar menu looks alright visually in an iPad. However, in an iPhone, it's kind of occupying too much space. Therefore, I am thinking to change the height to 45 for an iPhone.

What's the way to get the physical size of the screen? (not screen resolution) So I can make the height proportional to the physical size?

Comment: Are you trying to be able to tell the difference between the IPad and iPad mini?

Comment: @Holly I don't care what the device is, but would like to know the physical size of the screen, for example 5 inches vs 3 inches in height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider working with the frame property of the view of the current view controller.

```
self.view.frame.size.height and self.view.frame.size.width
```

You can make your other views proportional to those dimensions or based on their values, etc.

Comment: Aren't they representing the screen resolution instead of physical size?

Comment: @Joe nope, it's a point based system, this way you can keep things consistent and/or proportional across different devices and do different things with the space that you have in relation to the point sizes.

Comment: ok, I see. So I can say the point-based height is actually proportional to the physical height?

Answer (score 6):

You can get this information accessing [UIScreen](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIScreen/mainScreen) singleton.

To get size use `UIScreen.main.nativeBounds`. Also you can get scale coefficient of screen `UIScreen.main.nativeScale`.

Comment: This will only work on iOS 8 and above. What about iOS 7? I guess it will give a crash.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari, yes, it will crash. No one mention supported versions. If you want it on version < 8.0 you can use `bounds`.

Answer (score 0):

This code should adjust your scroll view to the size of the users screen.

self.view.frame.size.height and self.view.frame.size.width

Also, make sure that your constraints are all good.

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.frame.size.height` and `view.frame.size.width` to determine the size of different screen sizes. **This will work inside functions only.**

Answer (score 0):

You can always use:

```
UIScreen.main.bounds.width and UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

It works from any scope. For the brevity's sake you can have extensions like

```
extension UIScreen {
    static var screenHeight: CGFloat {
        UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }
    static var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
UIScreen.screenWidth
UIScreen.screenHeight
```